# How is reach interpreted in the Bestiary?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

When interpreting a creature's reach is that the amount of feet it can attack beyond its own space?

For example, the Gorilla in the Bestiary 1 has a space 10ft and reach 10ft.

Does that mean that the Gorilla occupies squares in a 2x2 area and can attack anything within a 6x6 area (the 8 other 2x2 areas that surround him) similar to how a medium creature with reach of 5ft can reach every square around them totaling a 3x3 area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean 'reach' and not 'range.'  Let's go look [at the Gorilla entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/primates/primate-gorilla):

> Melee 2 slams +3 (1d6+2)
>   Space 10 ft.; Reach 10 ft.

So how does reach work? Well, it's explained in the rules, and [the PFSRD has some helpful template pictures as well](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates).

Short answer is yes, the gorilla is 2x2 and can attack within a 6x6 area.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's what I meant.  Thanks for the link and for clearing this up.  Very helpful!